# I am having a problem with INDEX MATCH formula within an IF statement

Tags: excel

I am having a problem **nesting IF statements with INDEX MATCH**.

The value/data of **D17** could be **"Male" or "Female"**. I don't have any problem with a single IF, but when I try combining them, it says **#VALUE!**

Btw, here's the formula that I am using (which both works independently):

**Formula 1:**
=IF(D17="Male",(INDEX(DATA,MATCH('BMI SHEET'!F17,AGE,0),MATCH('BMI SHEET'!I17,BMI,0))))

**Formula 2:**
=IF(D16="Female",INDEX(DATA2,MATCH('BMI SHEET'!F16,AGEG,0),MATCH('BMI SHEET'!I16,BMIG,0))))

*How can I nest/combine these two formula?*

If D17 is "Male", find the value on table 1 (using index match), but if D17 is "Female", find the value on Table 2 (using index match).

[image]

The last column on the photo should give me the result...

Comment: If only `Male` or `Female` is possible, just use both true and false parameters inside `IF()`.

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how you can choose between the ranges for index(), after that you can expand the method:

=INDEX(IF(D17="Male",DATA,DATA2),MATCH('BMI SHEET'!F17,AGE,0),MATCH('BMI SHEET'!I17,BMI,0))

So, you can now do the same for both match() functions.

NOTE: I have assumed that the D16 in formula 2 is actually D17.

Comment: what if I wanted either result for male or female to be on a single cell?

Comment: ah, yes, that's actually d17...

Comment: Can you give me the exact formula? Still can't figure out how it will return a result if the gender indicated on the cell is Female.

Comment: So put this in a cell and test it : =IF(D17="Male",DATA,DATA2)  What it does is if D17 contains "Male" then the if() will evaluate to DATA, while if cell D17 contains "Female" then evaluates to DATA2 - (in fact whatever entered in D17 that is not "Male" will evaluate to DATA2. May need to trap that.